# How to create video from multiple gallery images store in array flutter ffmpeg

Tags: android, flutter, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I select images from gallery using multi_image_picker in flutter and store all images in array.

```
  try {
   resultList = await 
   MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
    maxImages: 300,
    enableCamera: true,
    selectedAssets: images,
    materialOptions: MaterialOptions(
      actionBarTitle: "Photo Editor and Video 
   Maker App",
    ),
  );
 }
```

User can select images from gallery and store in resultlist array.
Now I want to pass this array to ffmpeg to create video from all these images.

I try a lot and search almost all sites but fail. Here is my code.

```
Future<void> ConvertImageToVideo () async{
const String BASE_PATH = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/';
const String AUDIO_PATH = BASE_PATH + 'audiio.mp3';
const String IMAGE_PATH = BASE_PATH + 'image002.png';
const String OUTPUT_PATH = BASE_PATH + 'output02.mp4';
// final FlutterFFmpeg _flutterFFmpeg = FlutterFFmpeg();
if(await Permission.storage.request().isGranted){
  List<Asset> resultlist  = <Asset>[];
  String commandToExecute =
      '-r 15 -f mp3 -i ${AUDIO_PATH} -f image2 -i ${resultlist} -y ${OUTPUT_PATH}';
  await FFmpegKit.execute(commandToExecute).then((session) async {
    final returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();
    final state = await session.getState();
    if (ReturnCode.isSuccess(returnCode)) {
      print("ruuning   "+state.toString());
      print("video created " + returnCode.toString());
    } else if (ReturnCode.isCancel(returnCode)) {
      print("video cancel "  + returnCode.toString());
    } else {
      print("error " );
    }
  });
}else if (await Permission.storage.isPermanentlyDenied) {
  openAppSettings();
}
```

}

Comment: create a string using for loop for multiple files you picked and use ffmpeg concatination command.

Comment: please help me how to pass in ffmpeg command all user select images which are store in resultlist

Comment: String commandToExecute = ' -framerate 1/4.5 -i "$img1" -i "$img2" -i "$img3" -filter_complex "concat=n=3:v=0:a=0" -f mp3 -i ${AUDIO_PATH} -s 1080x1620 -y ${OUTPUT_PATH}'; i have this commend but when video generated it only show 1 image in video not other 2